# is startService() then calling startForeground in service same as startForegroundService call?

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

Context.startForegroungService indicates that we want to start foreground service. But we can start service by Context.startService and turn into foreground service by calling startForeground in the service.

Is there any behaviour difference between those?
What will we lose if we don't call startForegroundService but convert a normal started service to foreground?

Comment: Based on [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)), startForegroundService is the same as startService, but with the expectation that startForeground will be called very quickly after the service starts.

Comment: There are some cases where you can request to [launch a foreground service](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/foreground-services#background-start-restriction-exemptions) where regular start service would be thwarted by the system.

Answer (score -1):

By calling `startService()` followed by `startForeground()` within a service, you are manually starting a service and then promoting it to a foreground service. This approach is typically used for compatibility with older Android versions.

By the way, `startForegroundService()` was introduced in Android Oreo (API level 26) to start a foreground service directly. It combines both starting the service and making it a foreground service in a single call, simplifying the process. Obviously it's for Oreo and above to ensure compatibility.
I would suggest you to read this doc
[Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/foreground-services)

Comment: startService() followed by startForeground() cann`t be possible. to make it foreground service startForeground() method is defined.